# What is a "mail order record"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I encountered this term in the following text of [this article](https://jamesclear.com/successful-people-start-before-they-feel-ready):

> Four years later, he was looking for ways to grow his small magazine and started selling **mail order records** to the students who bought the magazine. The records sold well enough that he built his first record store the next year. After two years of selling records, he decided to open his own record label and recording studio.

I especially have trouble with the meaning of **record** here: Usually, a record is something done with a camera or something similar. However, this does not make much sense here, at least not for me.

Could you please explain the meaning and the context in this text? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In this sense he is referring to recorded music. Possibly of the vinyl 78 or 45 RPM styles from the 70's that have been making a comeback. A record store is a store that sells music CD's, records, cassettes, 8-tracks, etc. A record label is the production company of such. Mail order records means he is selling them by mail.

Answer (score 1):

In former times, before the modern age, people who wanted to hear music at home used a machine called a 'phonograph' (mainly American), or a 'gramophone', or a 'record player'. They could go to a record store (American) or record shop (UK) and buy plastic discs called 'phonograph (or gramophone) records' (or just 'records').

[image]